# How did I perform this teleport in Zelda BotW?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I just had a look in the Hero's Path and it's showing me some kind of teleport jump I seem to have performed:

It looks as if I teleported to a place I've never been before, which is not near a Shrine, Beast, or whatever teleportation target. I walked a few meters and then teleported away. You can clearly see that I never walked there, so I couldn't have placed the Travel Medallion there. You can find a [recording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCEXe.jpg) here.

How did I perform this jump?

Comment: Have you been playing for more than (I believe) 200 hours? Hero's Path only stores 200 hours of travel, but I'm not sure if it just stops recording after that point, or whether it erases your earliest recorded travel to make room for your new travel.

Comment: The start point MIGHT be where you fight Dark Beast Ganon. Can you save and quit the game during that boss fight? If so, it might have put you back to Hyrule Castle after.

Comment: @Kozaky I think you might be correct on that. [This Q&A](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/331452/does-playing-more-than-200-hours-in-botw-erase-the-first-bits-of-heroes-path) states that the Hero Path pauses while in dungeons, which I believe Hyrule Castle is considered a dungeon. If the paused state transferred to Hyrule Field during the Beast Ganon fight, that would make sense

Comment: @Kozaky Yes, this sounds as if it could be the case. I'll try this soon.

Comment: @Wondercricket While you're in Hyrule Castle, you can't access the map, but as you leave, your movements are show in Hero's Path.

Comment: @AdamV I did not play more than 200 hours. The bar is not even half filled. Besides, it should show you the last 200 hours, but don't quote me on that.

Comment: @Kozaky You're right with this trace being part of the final fight sequence. But you can neither save nor teleport during the battle... Make it an answer?

Comment: did you load an autosave by any chance?  I've noticed that autosave sometimes preserves the movement you did and just tp you back to the point of the autosave.

Comment: @MaxRied I have the game but haven't had the opportunity to test this and show evidence. If anyone else can prove my guess and show proof then they'd be deserving of giving a proper answer.

Answer (score 2):

After testing a bit on a save where I didn't face Ganon yet, I can say:

### Probably?

Looking through my Hero's Path, I came across a few similar disconnected teleports at the locations of the Divine Beast battles, the two below being particularly good examples.

[image: Examples of random teleport]

However, the final battle didn't seem to do the same thing for me. I saved some screenshots of the exact area you had in your jump before and after the battle, and I don't go in that area at all according to the Hero's Path.

I also took a screenshot of the location the battle started, and it does line up with what's shown in your recording.

[image: Location of final boss fight]

It's not quite the conclusive answer I wish this was, but perhaps in previous versions of the game, the final battle would be shown in the Hero's Path, or maybe it's a bit of a bug?

Either way, evidence shows that it was most likely caused by Hero's Path tracking you during Hyrule's hour of need.

Comment: I tested it and it was indeed the Ganon fight. I'd love to accept this answer, but it contradicts my experience...

Comment: Not worth a separate answer, but it could also be the Maz Koshia fight. EDIT: Actually no, the return point doesn't match.

Answer (score -1):

From my personal playing experience, I believe it happens when you load a new save file, or when you die.